# Customize UV Map of a Noise Texture Node

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm a newcomer to blender (as you can plainly see from the subject matter in the screenshots)

I'm having an issue with my Noise Texture node which doesn't seem to happen in video tutorials I've watched on the subject. I'm applying a texture to a torus using a UV Texture Coordinate node as the vector input (which is being used as a bump map), but the noise texture seems to get stretched more and more as it travels around the loop (from the picture, the bottom shows correctly, but as you travel counter-clockwise, the stretching becomes worse).

[image: stretched bump map]
[image: shader setup]

The geometry of the torus is sculpted a bit, but as you can see, the vertices are still fairly regular.

[image: vertices of the object]

I've tried other texture coordinates, but they look worse, with stretching happening irregularly.

[image: texture with other texture coordinates]

The color of the material is coming in from a square image made with Texture Paint, which might be stretched, but its linear and not noticeable. I was wondering if there is a way to visualize the UV map of the Noise Texture node so I can tweak it, akin to Texture Paint. Or if someone just has a straight up different solution, I'm open to anything.

Comment: I think you need to unwrap your model again, it almost looks like it's not unwraped at all

Comment: been playing around with the different unwrapping options, sometimes making seams. they all give me a lot of distortion, but they're better than what I had. Wondering what the default UV map was when I instantiated the texture paint image, it seemed like it projected it congruently to a square, somehow. Is there any way to see the noise texture laid out on the UV map?

Comment: You must have twisted the original UVs somehow, because by default the UVs of a torus should be straight, but you can still unwrap with the Follow Active Quads option to straighten it